# modal window external page

Tags: php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

The modal window not show up
here's the code

```
//index.php
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tambahpeg').click(function(){
            $('<div>').load('pages/pegawai/tambahpeg.php').dialog();
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<button id="tambahpeg">
</body>
```

here's the tambahpeg.php as the modal window content

```
            <form>
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /><br>

    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: where is the div in index.php you want to load form ? i did't see in your index.php

Comment: FYI, `load()` is async, you should use complete callback: `$('<div>').load('pages/pegawai/tambahpeg.php', function(){ $(this).dialog('open'); });`  Now it depends what plugin you use for dialog

Comment: It is working. Check it here in fiddle but replace the url. https://jsfiddle.net/mLmLkmt4/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this it could help you. jquery load() method will load the content before the page is parsed. So I have tried with **$.get()** you can also use **load()**

```
<body>
     <a href="#your_modal_id" data-toggle="modal" class="call_modal">Modal Load</a>

     <div class="modal fade" id="your_modal_id">
            <!-- your modal dialog styles and content -->
            <div class="modal-body">
           </div>
     </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click','.call_modal',function(evt)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var url = "pages/pegawai/tambahpeg.php"; 
        $('#your_modal_id').modal({
                            remote:$.get(url,function(response)
                            {
                                var hold = $(response);
                                $('#your_modal_id').find('.modal-body').empty().append(hold);
                            })
                          });
     });
});
```